# Have list item take all the height

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a page which simply looks like this:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>My List</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="has-header">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="#item of items">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons end>
          <button>Something</button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
      <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image"/>
      <h2 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="slide.title"></h2>
      <p [innerHTML]="slide.description"></p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Let says there are 100 items. I would like each item to take the full height. So you should not be able to see the next or previous item at all unless you scroll. I would like the height of every item to be the same which would be the size of ion-content I guess. How can I do this? I have tried playing around with height, min-height, positioning, flex, but have not been able to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` units in modern browsers. Support is [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

```css
ion-content {background: #f6f6b2;}
ion-content + ion-content {background: #b3f4b3;}
ion-content {display: block; height: 100vh;}
```

```html
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="#item of items">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons end>
          <button>Something</button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
      <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image"/>
      <h2 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="slide.title"></h2>
      <p [innerHTML]="slide.description"></p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>

<ion-content class="has-header">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="#item of items">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons end>
          <button>Something</button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
      <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image"/>
      <h2 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="slide.title"></h2>
      <p [innerHTML]="slide.description"></p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although this is not really what I am looking for. I don't want the items to be 100% of the screen I want it to be 100% of the ion-content area. This is because there is a header so 100vh automatically makes the item the size of the screen+the header. As well, I am not sure why ion-contents are being duplicated? I am running a list based off of the "items" dynamically (ngFor) I can't apply ion-content statically.